# Why doesn't mocha with hooks work with VS Code debugger?

Tags: mocha.js, vscode-debugger

Since adding a global `beforeAll` hook to my mocha unit tests they fail to work when launched via a launch.json debugger configuration.

The following `test` script in my package.json works fine to execute my global `beforeAll` hook if I'm running the npm script.

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --fiie src/tests/mochaHooks.js --loader=ts-node/esm src/tests/**/*.test.ts",
}
```

But when I attempt to launch the mocha unit tests in the Visual Studio Code debugger via the following configuration:

```json
"configurations": [{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Mocha Tests",
  "program": "node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha.js",
  "args": [
    "--file",
    "src/tests/mochaHooks.js",
    "--loader=ts-node/esm",
    "src/tests/**/*.test.ts",
    "--colors"
  ]
}]
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha.js --file src/tests/mochaHooks.js --loader=ts-node/esm src/tests/**/*.test.ts
(node:45105) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
warning:60

ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/markericson/Develop/sowrulesengine/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///Users/markericson/Develop/sowrulesengine/src/tests/mochaHooks.js:1:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
run.js:372
Process exited with code 1
```

The error is complaining about my mochaHooks.js and the following section of the code:

```js
exports.mochaHooks = {
  beforeAll(done) {
    initialization()
    done()
  },
}
```